# PHP retrieve array of items from a multidimensional array without looping?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I have a large array of arrays and each of these sub-arrays has an ID and some other info. Is there a way to access an array of just the ID's without using a loop?

Sort of like

```
$array[ALLOFTHEITEMS][Id];
```

I want to eventually compare these ID's to another flat array of ID's.
I would usually do a for loop and then just add the id of each item to a new array and then compare them. But is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its faster then foreach as I've never benchmarked it but an alternative to foreach would be:

php 5.3

```
$ids = array_map(function($data) { return $data['id']; }, $array);
```

php < 5.3

```
function reduceToIds($data) {
    return $data['id'];
}

$ids = array_map('reduceToIds', $array);
```

I normally use the foreach approach myself though.